# Select input ,selected Text codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have form with input select in the aplication/view codeigniter
and the form is submited by codeigniter, no ajax.

```
<select name="sel_options">
    <option value="1">hi</option>
    <option value="2" selected>bye</option>
</select>
```

in my aplication/controller

```
$this->input->post("sel_options");

result:
2
```

but i need the text ("bye");

Comment: value="bye" instead of value="2". Or, remove the value all together and the option label is used.

Comment: also I need the value

Comment: I think to do this, you'd require some Javascript.

Comment: in the case of using javascript would have to spend the entire data via ajax, there will be a way to do just to submit to codeigniter?

Comment: when you submit form select opitons value will be submitted. So produce your value field as you want.You cannot get both value and text.In that case you need to use tric. There are lots of way.here is one: set your value `2_bye` and explode the value with `_`

Comment: As Shaiful said, that would be `explode('_' , $this->input->post('sel_option');` where `<option value="2_bye" selected>bye</option>`

Answer (score 0):

When you post a value, it's going to use the **value** from the input. So in your case:

```
<select name="sel_options">
    <option value="1">hi</option>
    <option value="<!-- I'm Submitting this value -->" selected>bye</option> 
</select>
```

The value for the second option is 2 (`<option value="2" ... />`) if you wanted to pull in the value from the html ('bye'), you'd have to set the value to be bye.

```
<option value="bye" selected>bye</option>
```

Comment: also I need the value